# Electron context menu outside of electron browser window?

Tags: electron, contextmenu

Searched but didn't find an answer to this even on google, hopefully Stack Overflow heroes will have the answer :)

I'm considering building an app with electron, yet I need this information in order to know if electron is really the right solution.

Is it possible to add menu items to the right click menu when clicked outside electron browser window (like on pdf file for example or an actual web-browser like firefox) ?

Comment: You can instantiate your Menu (top of Window or Context Menu) in your main.js file . Have a look to the doc https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu

Comment: @AlainBUFERNE Hi, thanks for the answer, I looked into the page, didn't find anything there that mention top of window/context in the main.js file... can you please direct me more specifically to what I should be looking for in the linked page?

I'm extremely new to Electron, so my apologies for the amateur question.

Answer (score 0):

As I use it using remote because I want to take somme action in the renderer on option click.

In your renderer:

```
const { shell } = require('electron');
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const { Menu, MenuItem } = remote;

......
```

Declaration of the Menu

```
gMenuContextList = new Menu();
gMenuContextList.append(new MenuItem({ label: "Marquer", click() {
        //your code for this option 
} }));
gMenuContextList.append(new MenuItem({ type: 'separator' }));
gMenuContextList.append(new MenuItem({ label: 'Envoyer', click() {
        //your code for this other option 
} }));

.....
```

Code which intercept the contextmenu event on the window

```
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent the default context menu of Chromium
    gMenuContextList.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow()); //Show the Menu
  }, false);
```

Have a look also at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electron/electron_menus.htm

Comment: Thanks Alain,
This menu will show up inside the electron chromium window.

But my question is if it's possible to have electron menu outside the electron's window? in the windows10 window.

Comment: I don't think it could be possible, menus are native Chromium menus and we don't have css or positionning options available. Besides an application Menu seems to me normal to ashow up in the application window...isn't it

Comment: My goal is to have an additional actions in the menu when I choose a paragraph in pdfs outside of the electron window, of even if it's a text file. The right click menus inside electron is understood, what I find hard to know is whether it's possible to have the ability to add options to the right click menu outside of the electron window.

Comment: So you want to customise the contextMenu of your OS and should dig in this direction nothing to do with electron Menu

Comment: Thanks Alain, I appreciate that.
Can this be achieved with JavaScript or should I look for it somewhere else?